# How to use git log --oneline in gitpython

Tags: gitpython

I'm trying to extract list of commit messages by giving a start sha & end sha. It's easy in git using git log. 
But am trying to do it through gitpython library.
Could someone help me to achieve this?

in Git the command is like this :

`git log --oneline d3513dbb9f5..598d268f`

how do i do it with gitpython?

Answer (score 3):

The [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io) `Repo.iter_commits()` function ([docs](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.iter_commits)) has support for [ref-parse-style commit ranges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_ranges). So you can do:

```py
import git
repo = git.Repo("/path/to/your/repo")
commits = repo.iter_commits("d3513dbb9f5..598d268f")
```

Everything after that depends on the exact formatting you want to get. If you want something similar to `git log --oneline`, that would do the trick (it is a simplified form, the tag/branch names are not shown):

```py
for commit in commits:
    print("%s %s" % (commit.hexsha, commit.message.splitlines()[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure gitpython:

```py
import git
repo = git.Repo("/home/user/.emacs.d") # my .emacs repo just for example
logs = repo.git.log("--oneline", "f5035ce..f63d26b")
```

will give you:

```py
>>> logs
'f63d26b Fix urxvt name to match debian repo\n571f449 Add more key for helm-org-rifle\nbea2697 Drop bm package'
```

if you want nice output, use pretty print:

```py
from pprint import pprint as pp
```

```py
>>> pp(logs)
('f63d26b Fix urxvt name to match debian repo\n'
 '571f449 Add more key for helm-org-rifle\n'
 'bea2697 Drop bm package')
```

Take a note that `logs` is `str` if you want to make it a list, just
use `logs.splitlines()`

Gitpython had pretty much all similar API with git. E.g `repo.git.log` for `git log` and `repo.git.show` for `git show`. Learn more in [Gitpython API Reference](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#api-reference-toplevel)