# Iterate commits b/w 2 specified commits in GitPython

Tags: python, git, loops, commit, gitpython

```
import git
repo = git.Repo(repo_dir)
ref_name = 'master'
for commit in repo.iter_commits(rev=ref_name):
     <some code here>
```

This code iterates through all the commits. I want to iterate b/w 2 commits.
Just like `git log commit1...commit2`

How can I do the same using GitPython's iter_commits() method.

Comment: But do you know the code to execute the `git` command on terminal? If yes, you can create a function using `subprocess`. Then you can call the function to run the `git` command.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But I don't want go that way. I want to use this GitPython Lib

Comment: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.objects.commit.Commit.iter_items .  From `Commit.iter_items()` accepts a revision specifier, for which I believe Revision Range is also part of it.  Just pass `'commit1...commit2'`  should do the work.

Comment: If your question is exclusively about "how do I do thing X in gitpython", the gitpython tag is appropriate, but none of the other tags are appropriate as you'll get answers like the one from @Yusufsn. Note that [tag:commit] is about database transactions, not about Git commits.

Answer (score 6):

`repo.iter_commits(rev='1234abc..5678def')` works for me in `GitPython==2.1.11`

Example:

```
repo = git.Repo(repo_dir)
for commit in repo.iter_commits(rev='master..HEAD'):
     <some code here>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pure gitpython for that.

If you want to able to traverse certain commit (assuming the first
commit is HEAD), just use `max_count`. See [The Commit object](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#the-commit-object)

```py
two_commits = list(repo.iter_commits('master', max_count=2))
assert len(two_commits) == 2
```

if you want similar ability to `git log commit1...commit2` as you mentioned:

```py
logs = repo.git.log("--oneline", "f5035ce..f63d26b")
```

will give you:

```py
>>> logs
'f63d26b Fix urxvt name to match debian repo\n571f449 Add more key for helm-org-rifle\nbea2697 Drop bm package'
```

You can also use `logs = repo.git.log("f5035ce..f63d26b")` but it will give you all info (just like you use `git log` without `--oneline`)

if you want nice output, use pretty print:

```py
from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> pp(logs)
('f63d26b Fix urxvt name to match debian repo\n'
 '571f449 Add more key for helm-org-rifle\n'
 'bea2697 Drop bm package')
```

For more explanation about `repo.git.log`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55545500/6000005

Answer (score -2):

First, make a function to run the `git` command.

```
from git import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def execute_gitcmd(cmd, repo):
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, cwd=repo, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (out, error) = pipe.communicate()
    return out, error
    pipe.wait()
```

Then write any `git` command as you use on terminal, for example:

```
gitcmd = "git log -n1 --oneline"
```

Finally, call your function:

```
log = (execute_gitcmd(gitcmd, your_repository))
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: 1. The question was about GitPython. 2. The function has a major bug — `return` before `pipe.wait()`.